# How to export powerbi report .pbix using rest api in python | Reports - Export Report In Group using powerbi API

Tags: python, powerbi, azure-devops-rest-api, power-bi-report-server

The error I am getting in postman is 500 error. {
"Message": "An error has occurred."
}

Target URL: The target API is GET - https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/b7a888be-fcf3-4abd-b95c-2972171bc480/reports/9a8bef1b-e5b5-4504-a7db-17185f2703f0/Export

Header: {
Authorization: bearer 'access_tocken',
Content-Type: application/zip}

I am able to download report in powershell, want to convert it into python API.
Find below working code:

$ApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/reports/$reportId/Export"

## Export power BI file to current directory

$export_id = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $ApiUrl -Headers $auth_header -Method GET -ContentType "application/zip" -OutFile $filePath -TimeoutSec 0 -Verbose

Comment: 500 is a server side error, i.e. Power BI error. It shouldn't be your fault.

Comment: but Andrey Nikolov, same API is working using Powershell. so it should not be power bi error I think so.

Comment: probably in your python script you arent "login" correctly; Check this library:

https://github.com/cmberryau/pypowerbi/blob/master/pypowerbi/client.py

Comment: msta42a I have logged in correctly, because I am able to refresh dataset using same log in and Rest API python. SO that should not be issue.